# what data type is an Address?

Tags: c++, dictionary, types

I have a map that will store a string, and a corresponding address(memory) that contains a integer value or char value.

```
map<string,address> myMap;  //What datatype would address be?
```

I'm not sure what datatype I would put here any help would be great

Comment: What kind of address? A memory address? A street address?

Comment: memory Address @chris

Comment: How would you decide whether it's the address of an integer or a char?

Comment: Do you need to store an address? Why aren't you storing a `char` or an `int` by value directly?

Comment: @KerrekSB i'm given an assembly directive i.e (label .INT 90, or label .BYT 'R')  i'm then parsing the directive if it's an int i put the label and it's address that contains the value (char or int) into a map.

Comment: @Jack because then I would need two maps, I just want one map, one that holds the label and address of the value I want.

Comment: @JeremyConterio: that's a unsafe solution which doesn't make any sense, you want to store an address that would be either an `int` or a `char`? Just use an `union` and store it by value.

Comment: I get it - you're writing an assembler, and  need to build a symbol table of addresses corresponding to labels. Assuming you're using the address in any way as a calculation operand, store it as a numeric of a type capable of holding the largest address in your memory map. If unsure, just go for *long*.

Comment: @Eight-BitGuru, thanks :) i'm building a symbol table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider creating a custom class address that will contain the pointer and data type. In that way
    map<string,address> myMap;
will still work.

Comment: I forgot to mention: pointer will be of type 'void *' and data type information can be stored as a flag that will tell you whether it is int or char.

Answer (score 4):

An *address* is stored in a *compound type* known as a *pointer type*.

In order to get the *pointer type* that points to an `int` you use the '*' symbol:

```
int i; // integer
int* ip; // pointer to integer (stores the address of an int)

map<string, int*> myMap;  // pointer type pointing to an int
```

Answer (score 4):

So basically you want to map type generic addresses inside an `unordered_map`. Then just define your own datatype which is able to manage it safely, something like:

```
class Address
{
public:
  virtual uintptr_t getAddress() = 0;
  virtual ~Address() { }
};

template<typename T>
class RealAddress : public Address
{
private:
  T* address;
public:
  RealAddress(T* address) : address(address) { }
  uintptr_t getAddress() override { return address; }

}

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<RealAddress>> labels;
labels["foo"] = std::unique_ptr<Address>(new RealAddress<int>(address));
```

This is just to give you the idea, it's unclear if you have your data section of the assebly stored in the program itself (so you really have an `int*` or a `char*`) or if you just need a numeric address which is then relocated inside your assembler.

You can enrich the behavior, use an `enum class` or RTTI to distinguish between types and so on.

A really simpler solution would be to have something like

```
union Address
{
  char* addressChar;
  int* addressInt;
  Address(int* addressInt) : addressInt(addressInt) { }
  Address(char* addressChar): addressChar(addressChar) { }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

An "address" correspondents to a pointer in C or C++.

Try this for a pointer to an integer or an array of integer:

```
map<string, int*> myMap;
```

And this for a pointer to an char or an array of char:

```
map<string, char*> myMap2;
```

Answer (score 2):

The data type of a memory address is a *pointer*, which is denoted by the type that it points to, followed by an asterisk (`*`). For example, if you were storing the address of an `int`, your declaration would look like this:

```
map<string, int*> myMap;
```

If you were having trouble googling this, try searching for "pointer", rather than "address."

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idiomatic type you're looking for:

```
std::map<std::string, boost::variant<int*, char*>>
```